# LINQ - How to display data from multiple models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

i have this LINQ query on two tables

```
public ViewResult data()
        {
            var query = from a in DB.Album
                        join b in DB.Artists
                        on a.ArtistId equals b.ArtistId
                        where (b.ArtistId == 2)
                       select new { a ,b };

            return View(query.ToList());
        }
```

however i am confused how do i display these data i.e Artist table's Artist name and Album tables Album Name in my view?

i am trying something like this but it gives me a error

```
@model IEnumerable<test1.Models.Album>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "data";
}

<h2>data</h2>

@Model.Count()
<br />
<ul>
@foreach (var mod1 in Model)
{
    <li>

   @* @mod1.Genre.Name*@
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => mod1.Artist.Name)
    <br />
    @mod1.AlbumId
   <br />
    @mod1.Artist
    <br />
    @mod1.Title
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Error i get is

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`
2[test1.Models.Album,test1.Models.Artist]]', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[test1.Models.Album]'.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the exception because you are trying to pass a list of anonymous objects 
instead of a list of albums.

You can create a viewmodel so you can use that type as your model.

```
public class ArtistAlbumViewModel
{
    Artist Artist { get; set; }
    Album Album { get; set; }
}
```

Use this type when you return values from the query.

```
var query = from a in DB.Album
            join b in DB.Artists
            on a.ArtistId equals b.ArtistId
            where (b.ArtistId == 2)
            select new ArtistAlbumViewModel { Album = a, Artist = b };
```

Then you should strongly type your view to this type and edit the view according to your viewmodel.

```
@model IEnumerable<test1.Models.ArtistAlbumViewModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create A New View Model To Store all needed information

change your action to to return that ViewModel

Change your view to get model of your new viewmodel type, and fetch properties as required.